# DynamoDB updating list from Java fails

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I have next table:

```
@DynamoDBTable(tableName = "Table")
@Getter
@Setter
public class Table {

@DynamoDBHashKey
private String id;

@DynamoDBAttribute
private List<String> list;

}
```

I need to add values to list from Java. I tried next approach:

```
UpdateItemRequest request = new UpdateItemRequest()
    .withTableName("Table")
    .withKey(Collections.singletonMap("id", new AttributeValue().withS("123")))
    .withUpdateExpression("SET #ri = list_append(:vals, #ri)")
 .withExpressionAttributeNames(Collections.singletonMap("#ri","list"))
    .withExpressionAttributeValues(Collections.singletonMap(":vals",
        new AttributeValue().withSS("1","2","3")));
dynamoDB.updateItem(request);
```

But it fails without providing exact reason:

```
Unable to unmarshall exception response with the unmarshallers provided
```

I got two questions:

1. What is wrong with my request ?
2. Why I get unmarshall exception and how to fix it to get real reason ?

P.S. Other update requests work fine e.g. I can update id with same approach without problem.

Updated:

I've found a way to update values from Java

```
    UpdateItemRequest request = new UpdateItemRequest()
    .withTableName("Table")
    .withKey(Collections.singletonMap("id", new AttributeValue().withS("123")))
    .withUpdateExpression("SET #ri = list_append(:vals, #ri)")
    .withExpressionAttributeNames(Collections.singletonMap("#ri","list"))
    .withExpressionAttributeValues(Collections.singletonMap(":vals",
        new AttributeValue().withL(new AttributeValue().withS("1"),AttributeValue().withS("2"),AttributeValue().withS("3"))));
    dynamoDB.updateItem(request);
```

But it only allows to add one by one values in list, but I need to add several.

Answer (score 0):

```
private void updateList(String id, String field, List<AttributeValue> values) {
UpdateItemRequest request = new UpdateItemRequest()
    .withTableName("Table")
    .withKey(Collections.singletonMap("id", new AttributeValue().withS(id)))
    .withUpdateExpression("SET #field = list_append(:values, #field)")
    .withExpressionAttributeNames(Collections.singletonMap("#field", field))
    .withExpressionAttributeValues(Collections.singletonMap(":values",
        new AttributeValue().withL(values)));
dynamoDB.updateItem(request);
```

}

And use next method to convert to list of AttributeValue

```
private List<AttributeValue> buildAttributeValuesList(List<String> values) {
    return values
        .stream()
        .map(it -> new AttributeValue().withS(it))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```